# perl6 IO::Handle has no printf method, inconsistent with documentation, or I missed something?

Tags: file, printf, raku

I am trying to open a file for writing and use `printf` to do formatting, but documentation and reality do not seem to agree. Am I missing something?

```
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my $fh=open "test", :w;
IO::Handle<"test".IO>(opened, at octet 0)
> $fh.printf: "test";
No such method 'printf' for invocant of type 'IO::Handle'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

But my code seems okay according to documentation:

```
https://docs.perl6.org/routine/printf
```

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `printf()` example in [the docs](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/printf) doesn't work for me either:

```
~/p6_programs$ perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2016.11 built on MoarVM version 2016.11
implementing Perl 6.c.

~/p6_programs$ cat 4.pl6 
my $fh = open 'outfile.txt', :w;
$fh.printf: "The value is %d\n", 32;
$fh.close;

~/p6_programs$ perl6 4.pl6 
No such method 'printf' for invocant of type 'IO::Handle'
  in block <unit> at 4.pl6 line 3
```

You could use `sprintf()` as  a workaround:

```
my $fh = open 'outfile.txt', :w;
$fh.say: sprintf "The value is %d", 32;
$fh.close;
```

or `fmt()`:

```
my $fh = open 'outfile.txt', :w;
$fh.say: 32.fmt("The value is %d");
$fh.close;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will use sprintf workaround.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently `IO::Handle.printf` was added on [Nov 27, 2016](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/8774f245b2b15cc30305ce80e862f7a5511fc8aa) and Rakudo 2016.11 is tagged on [Nov 19](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/releases/tag/2016.11). So my guess is your Rakudo is older than that.

Comment: Thanks! I am using the Nov version: perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2016.11 built on MoarVM version 2016.11
implementing Perl 6.c.